# Getting NullPointerException but cant see one, can anyone point it out

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, ads, interstitial

It has to do with the Interstitial, I was getting the same problem with the Adview but solved it by adding the Adview to the xml and referencing in in java but you cannot do that with an Interstitial

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    AdView adView;
    InterstitialAd interstitial;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.test);
        AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID").build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        InterstitialAd interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId("banner");
        AdRequest adRequest2 = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                .addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID").build();
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest2);
        displayInterstitial();

    }

    public void displayInterstitial() {
        if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
    }
}
```

LOGCAT:

```
02-21 19:48:29.390: E/AndroidRuntime(1929): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 19:48:29.390: E/AndroidRuntime(1929): Process: com.adtest, PID: 1929
02-21 19:48:29.390: E/AndroidRuntime(1929): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.adtest/com.adtest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 19:48:29.390: E/AndroidRuntime(1929):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
02-21 19:48:29.390: E/AndroidRuntime(1929):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-21 19:48:29.390: E/AndroidRuntime(1929):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-21 19:48:29.390: E/AndroidRuntime(1929):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-21 19:48:29.390: E/AndroidRuntime(1929):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-21 19:48:29.390: E/AndroidRuntime(1929):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-21 19:48:29.390: E/AndroidRuntime(1929):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-21 19:48:29.390: E/AndroidRuntime(1929):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-21 19:48:29.390: E/AndroidRuntime(1929):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-21 19:48:29.390: E/AndroidRuntime(1929):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-21 19:48:29.390: E/AndroidRuntime(1929):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-21 19:48:29.390: E/AndroidRuntime(1929):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-21 19:48:29.390: E/AndroidRuntime(1929): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-21 19:48:29.390: E/AndroidRuntime(1929):     at com.adtest.MainActivity.displayInterstitial(MainActivity.java:40)
02-21 19:48:29.390: E/AndroidRuntime(1929):     at com.adtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
02-21 19:48:29.390: E/AndroidRuntime(1929):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
02-21 19:48:29.390: E/AndroidRuntime(1929):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-21 19:48:29.390: E/AndroidRuntime(1929):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
02-21 19:48:29.390: E/AndroidRuntime(1929):     ... 11 more
02-21 19:49:29.530: W/Ads(1929): Timed out waiting for ad response.
02-21 19:49:29.530: W/Ads(1929): Timed out waiting for ad response.
02-21 19:53:29.880: I/Process(1929): Sending signal. PID: 1929 SIG: 9
```

Comment: I don't know android, but I suggest that you mention the line which throws a NPE.

Comment: The only way that you could get help is by including the logcat.

Comment: 02-21 19:48:29.390: E/AndroidRuntime(1929): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: It tells you which line the NPE happened on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a *local* variable in your `onCreate()` and assigned the `InterstitialAd` instance to it:

```
InterstitialAd interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
```

This has nothing to do with the field in your class, thus when you call `displayInterstitial()` and reference the field in your class ... it's `null`

Also worth noting is that you're doing the same thing with `AdView`.

Answer (score 0):

```
InterstitialAd interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
```

You are not writing your new instance to the class member, but you're creating a local variable instead. Remove the `InterstitialAd` at the beginning and you should be fine.